# Changing framework from pure.css to bootstrap, without changing markup

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have a site styled up in [Pure](http://purecss.io/). How could I change a pure form to a bootstrap form without changing markup? My pure form is this:

```
 <form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
                    <div class="pure-control-group">
                        <label for="first-name">First name</label>
                        <input class="pure-input-1-2" type="text" id="first-name" placeholder="First name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="pure-control-group">
                        <label>Last name</label>
                        <input class="pure-input-1-2" type="text" placeholder="Last name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="pure-control-group">
                        <label>Middle names</label>
                        <input class="pure-input-1-2" type="text" placeholder="Middle names">
                    </div>

                    <div class="pure-control-group">
                        <label>Gender</label>
                        <select>
                            <option>Male</option>
                            <option>Female</option>
                            <option>Other</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <button>Save</button>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's predefined classes for labels and form controls.

Here's an example:

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="first-name">First Name:</label>
    <input type="first-name" class="form-control" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
    <input type="last-name" class="form-control" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="middle-names">Middle Name</label>
    <input type="middle-names" class="form-control" id="middle-name" placeholder="Middle names">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="sel1">Gender</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="gender">
      <option>Male</option>
      <option>Female</option>
      <option>Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form
```

Standard rules for form layouts:

- Always use `<form role="form">`
- Wrap labels and form controls in `<div class="form-group">`
- Add class .form-control to all textual `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>` elements

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have lots of forms on my site, I would rather not change markup at the moment while I am switching frameworks.

Comment: Plus, if you're planning on using Bootstrap, I would suggest just changing the markup. How many forms do you have?